# Retrieving href attribute (Link) from within a Div using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, attr

I am trying to grab the link (or href attribute) from an anchor tag within a div.

Here is my full HTML code:

```
<script> 
    var link = $('#jira_details a').attr('href');

    function useJira() {
        alert(link);
    }
</script>

<div id="jira_details">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="http://www.google.com">Bugs</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<input type="submit" value="test" onclick="javascript:useJira();" />
```

However, whenever I click the submit button, it alerts back with undefined every time.  I have even tried changing:

```
$('#jira_details a').attr('href');
```

to

```
$('#jira_details ul li a').attr('href');
```

So that it would go to that specific anchor tag, however it still did not work.  Any ideas on what the issue might be?

Comment: Your second solution [works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/SVyAF/).

Comment: `onclick="javascript:useJira();"` Remove that `javascript:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The var link is being written before the dom is loaded.

If the anchor url never changes, you can do:

```
<script> 

$(function(){
  var link = $('#jira_details a').attr('href');
});

function useJira(){
  alert(link);
}
</script>
```

OR, if the href could change:

```
<script> 
function useJira(){
  var link = $('#jira_details a').attr('href');
  alert(link);
}
</script>
```

Comment: kayo can we use class name instead of class id ? i tried that i keep getting undefinded inside window.onload = () => {
  const backButton = document.querySelector('.my.classname');

  backButton.addEventListener('click', () => {